# Ionic 3 form validation not work when push page within onAuthStateChanged(firebase) function

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic3

## [update]

just use **authState**.It's working for me

```
constructor(public afAuth:AngularFireAuth,public navCtrl: NavController,) {
      this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
           if(user)
           {
                console.log('welcome')
           }
           else
           {
                this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage)
           }
      })
 }
```

---

I'm using ionic3 and firebase

When i navigate to login page within onAuthStateChanged(firebase) function.
My form validate in login page not work.
Only work when navigate from outsite this function.

**home.ts**

```
export class HomePage {

 constructor(public afAuth:AngularFireAuth,public navCtrl: NavController,) {
      this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user =>{
           if(!user)
           {
                this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage
           }
      })
  }

 }
```

### login.ts

```
export class LoginPage {
 loginForm: FormGroup;
 constructor(public alertCtrl: AlertController,public fb: FormBuilder,public navCtrl: NavController,public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, public navParams: NavParams) {
      this.createForm()
 }
 createForm() {
      this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
           'user': ['',Validators.compose([Validators.required]),],
           'pass': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      });
 }
 showAlert() {
      const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                title: 'Something wrong',
           subTitle: 'Wrong email or password',
           buttons: ['OK']
      });
      alert.present();
 }
 login()
 {
      if(this.loginForm.valid)
      {
           var username = this.loginForm.get('user').value
           var password = this.loginForm.get('pass').value
           this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(username,password).catch((err)=>{
                console.log(err)
                this.showAlert()
           })
      }
 }
```

**login.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm">
      <p class="text-danger bg-dark p-2" *ngIf="loginForm.controls['user'].errors && !loginForm.controls['user'].pristine">required</p>
      <input type="text"  placeholder="Email" class="form-control input-style" formControlName="user">
                               
      <p class="text-danger bg-dark p-2" *ngIf="loginForm.controls['pass'].errors && !loginForm.controls['pass'].pristine">required</p>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Password" formControlName="pass"  class="form-control input-style">                              
 </form>               
 <button  type="submit" [disabled]="loginForm.invalid" (click)="login()" class="ghost-round full-width">Login</button>
```

Comment: Not sure about this problem but i would recommend you to put the begining of your code into the ngOnInit() hook. All injectables are ready from that point instead of the constructor. Let me know.

Comment: not work.but work when i code like this
public loginStatus = new BehaviorSubject(false);
constructor() {
this.afAuth.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user =>{
               if(user)
               {
                    this.loginStatus.next(true)
               }
               else
               {
                    this.loginStatus.next(false)
               }
          })
this.loginStatus.subscribe(data => {
               console.log(data)
               if(this.loginStatus.value == false )
               {
                    this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage)
  }
 })
}

Comment: i had to push 2 times to make it work @Becario

Comment: @BecarioSenior Do you have any idea

Comment: I cann't read serialized code.